# Problems With Search Bar Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was trying to implement a Search Bar and when i tested, it worked in a strange way: only the last letters could be found, or the whole name.
  I'm sorry if the problem is simple to solve, i'm new to Ruby On Rails, and i really need this fixed and i couldn't find out how to fix it myself.
  (Sorry about my bad English)

Here's my html:

```
<div class="search">
  <%= form_for root_path, :url => {:action => "search"}, class: 'navbar-form' do |f| %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'ad[price_min]', @ads_min, :placeholder => "Price min", class: "form-control embed-responsive-item" %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'ad[price_max]', @ads_max, :placeholder => "Price max", class: "form-control embed-responsive-item" %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'ad[title]', @ads_text, :placeholder => "Search xablau by name", class: "form-control embed-responsive-item" %>
  <button class="btn btn-info" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Here's my controller:

```
def search
  if params[:ad].present?
    @ads_min = params[:ad][:price_min]
    @ads_max = params[:ad][:price_max]
    @ads_title = params[:ad][:title]

    @ads = Ad.search( params[:ad] )
  else
    @ads = Ad.all
  end
  render :action => 'index'
end
```

Here's my model:

```
def self.search(query)
  price_min = query[:price_min].present? ? "price >= #{query[:price_min].to_f}" : nil
  price_max = query[:price_max].present? ? "price <= #{query[:price_max].to_f}" : nil
  title = query[:title].present? ? "title LIKE '%#{query[:title]}'" : nil

  query = [title, price_min, price_max].compact.join(" AND ")

  return Ad.where( query )
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use **ILIKE** and `%text%` instead of `%text`

```
title = query[:title].present? ? "title ILIKE '%#{query[:title]}%'" : nil
```

Because `%text%` matches with any string that contains `text` but `%text` matches only with string that have `text` on the end of string.

PS: you have to rewrite the `search` method because it's insecure put a user based text in sql. Do not do that `"title LIKE '%#{query[:title]}'"` Write something like that `where("title ILIKE ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")`

Comment: I would give + if you use placeholders so that he does not get an SQL injection attack.

Comment: I just tried this and got this error message:

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Index#search
SQLite3::SQLException: near "ILIKE": syntax error: SELECT "ads".* FROM "ads" WHERE (title ILIKE '%a%')

Comment: @Zebiro use just `LIKE` I thought you're using psql. SQLite doesn't have ILIKE function.